# JavaScript in workflow in Adobe Campaign

Tags: javascript, forms, adobe, field, workflow

Can anyone helps us with the JavaScript code that's required in the following Adobe Campaign workflow:

[image]

...for JavaScripts, "Trigger Double Opt-in in Email," and "Subscribe to the service."

We are creating a double opt-in process for subscribers (they subscribe to a service in a web form but need to confirm their subscription through a follow-up confirmation email).

This "double opt-in" process is required for European subscribers as it is required by law in Europe.

We created a form with the **form field**, "Country," and if any European residence selects a European country of residence in the form field, then an automated confirmation email is sent to confirm their subscription; for anyone outside the European union (in the US, for example), they are subscribed to the service (without a confirmation [double opt-in] email process).

Can anyone help us with the JavaScript or help us get going?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. From 1st js, call a workflow (i.e. mailsenderWkf) using postevent. Send required parameters with this function call.
2. If you are using out of the box recipient table to send emails, please skip this section. Otherwise create a link with your recipient table to the out of the box subscription table.
3. Use out of the box subscription mechanism to let the user subscribe through email.
4. In 2nd js, use the out of the box subscribe function (available in jsapi document) to subscribe the user directly.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using JavaScript, you can use message center.

1. Create a workflow for form filling campaign.
2. When recipient submits the form an event will be triggered in the campaign there by activating message center workflow.
3. A new email confirmation mail will be recieved by recipients.
4. Once the recipient clicks on confirmation link, optin data will be stored in campaign.

Please correct me if I'm wrong and if this works please let me know the same.

Thanks